# Registering generic decorators in Windsor

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container, decorator

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

I want to wrap all my handlers with this caching decorator:

```cs
public class CachingQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    public CachingQueryHandler(
        IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler,
        IQueryCachingRule<TQuery, TResult> cachingRule,
        ITaggedCacheProvider cache)
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Thats how I registering components in Windsor:

```
container.Register(
    Component
        .For(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(CachingQueryHandler<,>)),
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyContaining<GetUserCourseStatesHandler>()
        .BasedOn(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
        .WithServiceBase()
)
```

In few articles I read that Windsor can wire a decorator chain automatically, if all components are registered in a valid order. But in my case Windsor just ignores my `CachingQueryHandler` registration when I trying to resolve any `IQueryable<,>`.
In container's private field named `Potentially Misconfigured Components` I found this warning:

> Some dependencies of this component could not be statically resolved.
>   IGSystems.Common.CQRS.CachingQueryHandler'2 is waiting for the
>   following dependencies:
>   - Service 'IQueryHandler'2' which points back to the component itself. A dependency cannot be satisfied by the component itself, did you
>   forget to register other components for this service?

Comment: What is the reason that `IQueryHandler` uses `in` and `out` keywords? This communicates that query handlers are variant, which seems unlikely to me. You use your query handlers in an (co/contra)variant manner?

Comment: No, it was a ReSharper's suggestion to use that keywords. I accepted it to suppress warning, but I thought it will not have bad consequences. Am I right?..

Comment: I don't believe that very bad things will happen when you do this :-), but I think it gives the suggestion that your query handlers can be resolved in a variant manner, which is probably not something you want and probably not easy to achieve with Castle Windsor. For an interface such as `IEventHandler`, it would be more common to need variance. See for instance my question about it [here](http://bit.ly/qcMCnu), and my blog post about doing variance with Simple Injector [here](http://bit.ly/rpjFPU). btw. Did you come across [this article](http://bit.ly/s3UUyv)?

Comment: I have not read the article, but my solution is identical to the proposed there. It surprised me. :)

Comment: When you're following SOLID, this is what you will end up with. So you're SOLID :-)

Comment: But I still don't know how to register a generic decorator in Windsor, which will apply to convention-based registrations. Maybe there is only single solution: switch to Simple Injector...

Answer (score -1):

Well if you want your caching query handler to decorate your real implementation, you should reorder your registrations.

```
container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyContaining<GetUserCourseStatesHandler>()
        .BasedOn(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
        .WithServiceBase(),
Component
        .For(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(CachingQueryHandler<,>))
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't work.