# Registering Generic decorators in castle windsor?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am trying to decorate my command handlers using castle windsor but it seems that my registrations are not correct as the class is not decorated.

I have the following installer:

```
internal class CommandsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IDbConnection>()
                .UsingFactoryMethod(() => ConnectionHelper.GetOpenDbConnection(Connection.DatabaseName.ReedOnline))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(
            Classes
                .FromAssemblyContaining<EcruiterCommands>()
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Commands"))
                .WithService
                .AllInterfaces().LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(
            Classes
                .FromAssemblyContaining<EcruiterCommands>()
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("CommandHandler"))
                .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(Component.For(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof (TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<>))
            .IsDefault()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());

        container.Register(Component.For(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof (ExceptionHandlingCommandHandlerDecorator<>))
            .IsDefault()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());            
    }
}
```

and this is my decorator:

```
namespace TempSearch.Ioc.Decorators.CommandHandlers
{
    public class TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    {
        private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated;

        public TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated)
        {
            this.decorated = decorated;
        }

        public void Handle(TCommand command)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                decorated.Handle(command);
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Additionally I am wondering if my decorators should live in the composition root or in the assembly of the class they are decorating. Right now I have moved them to the composition root as castle windsor was trying to register my decorators along with the other classes and I would get the error:

```
Component TempSearch.Command.Data.Decorators.TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator`1 could not be registered.
There is already a component with that name.
Did you want to modify the existing component instead?
If not, make sure you specify a unique name.
```

Comment: "_...am having difficulty_"  What difficulty would that be?  Also try to stick to one question per post.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk is right. I tried answering your question about decorators before realizing the edit. Please rollback and open another question instead

Comment: I Have opened another question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627510/castle-windsor-instances-are-registered-as-singleton-even-though-explicitly-decl

Comment: Why are you registering your commands? Commands are not services but messages (they contain the runtime data that you pass through the system) and messages should not be registered in your container.

Comment: @Steven those arent commands, they are just classes that have Insert,Update,Delete statements in them and Im trying to move away from that and to your implementation in your blog, since you are here, do you think I would see any benefits with the command handler pattern in an MVC app? we already have a seprate query and commands project but we dont use command handler patterns. I am asking because usually this pattern is used in distributed systems. and most of what we do is in the query side.

Comment: @Xerxes: Good to hear you're moving away from this CRUD stuff. About your question: It all depends on what the application you are building. My last few applications where all MVC and WinForm apps and I used the command/handler pattern on all of them with great benefit. None of those applications where distributed applications btw. This pattern is not just for distributed apps. The pattern is just an implementation of SOLID and the SOLID principles are good in for any application.

Answer (score 2):

First, regarding the "already registered" error, you are registering your component twice

```
container.Register(
    Classes
        .FromAssemblyContaining<EcruiterCommands>()
        .BasedOn(typeof (ICommandHandler<>))
        .WithService.AllInterfaces()
        .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

This registers all classes that are based on `ICommandHandler<>`, so `TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator` is already registered

Regarding the decorator pattern you are going for, I'd implement it using castle's [interceptors](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Interceptors.ashx?HL=interceptor) instead. I found that Decorators patterns are [not very easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755727/multiple-decorator-pattern-in-castle-windsor) to do in Castle; the answer linked is quite old and Castle has changed since then so I may be wrong but interceptors are what you want.

Comment: I tried explicitly only bind the instances that have "CommandHandler" at the end tried that but it still doesnt work, any ideas?

Comment: Apart from what I already wrote not much more. You can take a look at the order-specific registration to see if it helps to set up the decorator, but I'd go with interceptor

Comment: @Xerxes: If you read Krzysztof Kozmic's answers here on Stackoverflow about applying generic decorators in Castle Windsor, you'll find that Castle's support for this limited and Krzysztof advices to use interception instead. This is of course isn't a very satisfying answer, because interception forces your code to have a dependency on the the interception library and leads to code that is much less readable, much less maintainable.

Comment: @Steven thanks steven, appreciate the help, on another note I was reading your answer here on having a single dbContext per web request, I use micro Orms and I was wondering if it would be fine to register my IdbConnection to be resolved per web request and late bound using a factory method?

Comment: @Xerxes: My current preference is to prevent injecting any state related elements into the object graph completely. Instead, try to build an object graph that is built-up by singletons completely. e.g. instead of injecting an `DbContext` into a handler, inject an `IContextProvider` that contains a `Context` property that retrieves the `DbContext` for the current request. Or -even better- have an `IUnitOfWork` abstraction with a single `IQueryable<T> Set<T>()` method. The `IUnitOfWork` can be a singleton and the `Set<T>` method retrieves the underlighing `DbContext` for the current request.

Comment: @Xerxes: btw, are you sure you want to [switch to interception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629645/castle-windsor-intercepter)? You might be better of using Simple Injector instead.

Comment: @Steven believe me as much as I want to it will be a losing fight to try to convince the other developers to switch to any other technology where I work, unless I do it without anyone knowing then I'm stuck.

Comment: @Xerxes: That sucks. I wish you the best of luck. But at least you are using the right patterns. That's the most important part.