# Castle windsor intercepter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container, interception

I am trying to intercept calls to the Handle method on my command handlers.
this process works fine when I explicitly register each command handler, the problem is that my generic registration of the command handlers and the interceptor is not correct.

exception:

> An exception of type
>   'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException'
>   occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ComponentActivator: could not proxy
>   TempSearch.Command.Data.CommandHandlers.AddTempsJobCommandHandler

It looks like it cannot find the intercepter as it says that
some components are misconfigured:

> "Some dependencies of this component could not be statically
>   resolved.\r\n'TempSearch.Command.Data.CommandHandlers.AddTempsCandidateAvailabilityCommandHandler'
>   is waiting for the following dependencies:\r\n- Component
>   'TempSearch.Ioc.ExceptionHandlingIntercepter' (via override) which was
>   not found. Did you forget to register it or misspelled the name? If
>   the component is registered and override is via type make sure it
>   doesn't have non-default name assigned explicitly or override the
>   dependency via name.\r\n"

The interface:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

an example Command Handler:

```
public class AddTempsCandidateAvailabilityCommandHandler 
    : ICommandHandler<TempsCandidateAvailability>
{
    private readonly IDbConnection connection;

    public AddTempsCandidateAvailabilityCommandHandler(
        IDbConnection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void Handle(TempsCandidateAvailability command)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

the registeration:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(
        Component.For<IDbConnection>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => ConnectionHelper.GetOpenDbConnection(
                Connection.DatabaseName.ReedOnline))
            .LifestylePerWebRequest());

    container.Register(
        Classes
            .FromAssemblyContaining<EcruiterCommands>()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Commands"))
            .WithService
            .AllInterfaces().LifestylePerWebRequest());

    container.Register(
        Classes
            .FromAssemblyContaining<EcruiterCommands>()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("CommandHandler"))
            .WithService.AllInterfaces()
            .LifestylePerWebRequest()
            .Configure(c => c.Interceptors<ExceptionHandlingIntercepter>()
                .LifestyleTransient()));
}
```

the intercepter:

```
[Transient]
public class ExceptionHandlingIntercepter : IInterceptor
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo Execute = 
        typeof(ICommandHandler<>).GetMethod("Handle");

    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public ExceptionHandlingIntercepter(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method != Execute)
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        finally
        {
            kernel.ReleaseComponent(invocation.Proxy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any further details from an inner exception?

Comment: @phil please see edited question, also it works fine when I explicitly register each command handler, the problem is that my generic registeration of the command handlers and the intercepter is not correct.

Comment: I think @samy has nailed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must register the interceptor itself in order to let Castle resolve it when initializing your command handlers. Add the following to your registration:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ExceptionHandlingIntercepter>(); // should be enough
```

I like naming my interceptors to register them by name (don't know why, since your way should work fine)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using this code:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {    
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IInterceptor>()
                    .ImplementedBy<ExceptionHandlingIntercepter>().LifestyleTransient(),
                Classes
                    .FromAssemblyContaining<EcruiterCommands>()
                    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("CommandHandler"))
                    .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                    .LifestylePerWebRequest().Configure(c => c.Interceptors<ExceptionHandlingIntercepter>())
                );
        }
```